# API Currency data into an LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, rest-api, api

I am working on putting the results of a Currency API into a data table! I have set the api up in an apex class and the data comes through fine but I can't seem to get the data to display in the table can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?  I think it's on the formatExchangeData function I have written as I am trying to map the data, Maybe a map isn't what I need but not sure what else to do! I am quite rusty with JS so any help/examples would really benefit me! THANK YOU!!

API CLASS:

```
public with sharing class apiCalloutClass {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Map<string, object> getExchange() {
        HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
        httpRequest.setEndpoint('http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=0890b65238c39945ef817557bee851ed');
        httpRequest.setMethod('GET');

        Map<String, Object> exchangeJsonData = new Map<string, Object>();
        String strResponse = null;

        try {
            Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse httpResponse = http.send(httpRequest);
        if(httpResponse.getStatusCode()== 200){
            strResponse = httpResponse.getBody();
        } else {
            throw new CalloutException(httpResponse.getBody());
        }
            
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
        if(!String.isBlank(strResponse)){
            exchangeJsonData = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(strResponse);
        }
        if(!exchangeJsonData.isEmpty()){
            return exchangeJsonData;
        }else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

LWC JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import apiCalloutData from '@salesforce/apex/apiCalloutClass.getExchange';

const columns = [
    {label: 'Date', value: 'date'},
    {label: 'Rates', value: 'rates'},
    {label: 'Base Currency', value: 'base'}
]
export default class ApiCalloutLWC extends LightningElement {
    result=[];
    columns = columns;

    connectedCallback(){
        this.fetchCurrency();
    }
    fetchCurrency(){
        apiCalloutData().then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            this.formatExchangeData(response.data);
            console.log(this.result);
        }).catch(error=>{
            console.error(error);
        })
    }
    formatExchangeData(res){
        //issue seems to be here where it can't read the map I am creating of the API data
        this.result = res.map((item)=>{
         return { ...item, id: id, date: date, rates: rates, base:base}
    })
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Currency Exchange Rate" icon-name="standard:currency">
        <lightning-datatable
        key-field="id"
        data={result}
        columns={columns}
        hide-checkbox-column="true">
        </lightning-datatable>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't `return null;` This makes your code unnecessarily complicated, as now you have to do a null check for no reason. You should [Say No To Null](https://www.google.com/search?q=say+no+to+null).

Second, data tables can only show Array-formatted values, not Map-formatted values. You're correct that you've run into a problem in your code. Either fix it on the server, or you can trivially fix it on the client side:

```
this.result = Object.keys(res).map(key => {key, ...res[key]});
```

`Object.keys` returns the keys in a Map/Object, which we then pass in to `Array.prototype.map`, and now we have a properly formatted Array we can use in the data table.